# Replace - if preceeded by alphabet

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace hyphen character with space if it is **NOT** enclosed by digits on both sides.

```
 string str = "Hefer 789-567 dfg-5mh";
            str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[a-zA-Z]\-(\d+)", "$1");
```

**Output**

> Hefer 789-567 df5mh

**Desired output**

> Hefer 789-567 dfg 5mh

Comment: please see second and third line of my post having the regular expression

Comment: `$1` is only the digit (or digits) (first capturing group). Try `$0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are describing in your title can be solved using this:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=[A-Za-z])-", " ");
```

The problem you are describing in the body of your question can be solved using this:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!\d)-|-(?!\d)", " ");
```

Or without lookaround:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"([^\d])-|-([^\d])", "$1 $2");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use negative lookahead and lookbehind: `(?<!\d)-|-(?!\d)` says "match a `-` that is not preceeded by a `\d` or a `-` that is not followed by a `\d`".

Thus your regex would be something like

```
string str = "Hefer 789-567 dfg-5gh";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!\d)-|-(?!\d)", " ");
```

Edit: Note that this also replaces hyphens at the start or end of the string. If you want to avoid this you can use `(?<!\d|^)-(?=.)|(?<=.)-(?!\d|$)` or `(?<=[^\d])-(?=.)|(?<=.)-(?=[^\d])`.